# Bootstrap and asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I started learning asp.net core, install via nuget bootstrap, but instead of folders with styles and scripts, only dependencies are installed. Originally created an empty project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @bluemoon6790 
I learn from the book of Freeman, I repeat everything after him. I do not think that he is a fool, and does not know how to create projects....

Answer (score -2):

Possible problems:
- Visual Studio access to the root folder (run as admin would fix it);

Nevertheless I suggest you to remove the nuget reference and install it manually:
 - https://getbootstrap.com/
 - Example here: https://damienbod.com/2018/06/26/updating-asp-net-core-identity-to-use-bootstrap-4/